# Simulating interaction between two users in Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

I have to register two users and simulate interaction between them (for example, a conversation).
I can do the following: register the first user, then register the second, sign in using first user's data, write message to the second user and sign out. Then sign in using the second user's data, answer to the message and sign out.
Is it possible to implement users' conversation without signing out if the system requires enabled cookies for users?

Comment: I implemented the first scenario you described. Because writing messages to DB and then reading is not an option. Something strange happens when setting cookies, so my variant also failed. Thank you for attention!

Comment: Maybe someone, who hasn't read the question yet, can suggest some trick with cookies. I think it would be right to wait for a while...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't want to sign out as it's in your scenario.

You could code your scenario with:

- [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
- [Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- [CSV Dataset config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)

Then organise you CSV like this:

```
    First Line : U1_LOGIN, U2_LOGIN,U1_MESSAGE,U2_MESSAGE
    Second Line : U3_LOGIN, U4_LOGIN,U3_MESSAGE,U4_MESSAGE
    ...
```

Finally organize your Test Plan like this:

```
     CSV Data Set
     Thread Group
     \- CookieManager
     \- OnceOnlyController
        \- Register U1_LOGIN
        \- SignOut U1_LOGIN
        \- Register U2_LOGIN
        \- SignOut U2_LOGIN
     \- SignIn U1_LOGIN
     \- Write Message U1_MESSAGE
     \- SignOut U1_LOGIN
     \- SignIn U2_LOGIN
     \- Write Message U2_MESSAGE
     \- SignOut U2_LOGIN
```

Of course it's a draft , add all necessary assertions

Another option if you don't want to signout.
Create 2 thread groups:

- one that writes
- one that reads

This will require you to fill database with messages to read before the test.
It's up to you to say if it will simulate correctly your system.

But the option you intend to take seems to me wrong cause it is not maintanable regarding jmeter and not sure it reflects a real use case

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE. The test plan you have described is the one I can implement, but don't want to do. I want to write a test plan without additional "sign out"-s because when I test manually using two different browsers I don't need to sign out. I found how to save cookies, how to clear them and how to set them, but setting doesn't work at the moment (I use CookieManager and Cookie classes). I hope to solve this problem today.